# semantic for a factory method, regarding validation messages

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have a user model, and I want to generate a user with a class method.

I used to do something like this :

```
def self.generate_user(params)
  user = user.new
  # Some work on the user model
  user.save ? user : nil
end
```

With this, I can know if the user is created or not pretty easily, however, I can't access its error messages.

So I am considering these two options :

### Option 1, return status and model

```
def self.generate_user(params)
  user = user.new
  # Some work on the user model
  return user.save, user
end
```

Then I have to get the results this way : `ret, user = User.generate_user(params)`

### Option 2, return only the user, check with `valid?`

```
def self.generate_user(params)
  user = user.new
  # Some work on the user model
  user
end
```

Then :

```
user = User.generate_user(params)
if user.valid?
  # Do stuff
end
```

What option do you prefer ? Do you have any other ? Maybe with the use of exceptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions, definitely. More Ruby-like, and ActiveRecord throws an exception if you use [create!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21) and it fails:

```
def self.generate_user(params)
  User.create! do |u|
    # Do some stuf wth user
  end
end

begin
  user = User.generate_user(params)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
  # Find errors here : e.record.errors
  # Something on rescue
end
```

Comment: Seems to be the best choice, I edited your answer to show how to get the record and the errors from the exception

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
def self.generate_user(params)
  user = User.create do |u|
    # Do some stuff with user
  end
  user
end
```

and then:

```
user = User.generate_user(params)
if user.valid? # or user.persisted?
  # alright
end
```